# Flutter: Block Gestures to underneath widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, gesture

I have a stack with some widget, and I want tat the most in top widget blocks all the gestures to the underneath widgets.

I've tried with a GestureDetector and opaque behaviour but does not work.

What is the correct approach?

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **IgnorePointer** widget to block any gesture for it's child.

```dart
IgnorePointer(
    child: MyWidget(),
    ignoring: true, // or false to disable this behavior
)
```

Also any widget that is partially overflowing the stack will not receive gestures.

Answer (score 2):

If you have shared some code, that would be better, so now I can just give you an idea, you can try `AbsorbPointer`.

```
AbsorbPointer(child: YourWidget())
```